# im currently making a calculator using python an tkinter for the GUI. I have created all the buttons and a text box necessary

Tags: python, tkinter

So the problem is i dont know how to display the contentents of the button i'm pressing on the text box and i need some help with the code. As in where to make changes and where to make some improvements. And another problem i encountered is when the window is minimized the buttons overlap each other i need them to stay the same even after minimized the window.
This is the code i've written so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.title('Manoj Calculator')
label = tk.Label(window, text = 'The calculator created by manoj welcomes you')
label.pack()

text_box = tk.Text(window , bg = "#ffffff" , fg = "#0000ff" , height = 1 , width = 160)
text_box.place(relx = 0.5 , rely = 0.4 , anchor = "center")
                   
btn1 = tk.Button(window , text = "1" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn1.pack(side = "top")                 
btn1.place(relx = 0.1 , rely = 0.5 , anchor = "center")

btn2 = tk.Button(window , text = "2" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn2.pack(side = "top")                 
btn2.place(relx = 0.14 , rely = 0.5 , anchor = "center")

btn3 = tk.Button(window , text = "3" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn3.pack(side = "top")                 
btn3.place(relx = 0.18 , rely = 0.5 , anchor = "center")

btn4 = tk.Button(window , text = "4" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn4.pack(side = "top")                 
btn4.place(relx = 0.1 , rely = 0.6 , anchor = "center")

btn5 = tk.Button(window , text = "5" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn5.pack(side = "top")                 
btn5.place(relx = 0.14 , rely = 0.6 , anchor = "center")

btn6 = tk.Button(window , text = "6" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn6.pack(side = "top")                 
btn6.place(relx = 0.18 , rely = 0.6 , anchor = "center")

btn7 = tk.Button(window , text = "7" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn7.pack(side = "top")                 
btn7.place(relx = 0.1 , rely = 0.7 , anchor = "center")

btn8 = tk.Button(window , text = "8" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn8.pack(side = "top")                 
btn8.place(relx = 0.14 , rely = 0.7 , anchor = "center")

btn9 = tk.Button(window , text = "9" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn9.pack(side = "top")                 
btn9.place(relx = 0.18 , rely = 0.7 , anchor = "center")

btn0 = tk.Button(window , text = "0" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn0.pack(side = "top")                 
btn0.place(relx = 0.14 , rely = 0.8 , anchor = "center")

btn_point = tk.Button(window , text = "." , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_point.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_point.place(relx = 0.1 , rely = 0.8 , anchor = "center")

btn_back = tk.Button(window , text = "<-" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_back.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_back.place(relx = 0.18 , rely = 0.8 , anchor = "center")

btn_plus = tk.Button(window , text = "+" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_plus.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_plus.place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.5 , anchor = "center")

btn_minus = tk.Button(window , text = "-" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_minus.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_minus.place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.6 , anchor = "center")

btn_mul = tk.Button(window , text = "X" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_mul.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_mul.place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.7 , anchor = "center")

btn_div = tk.Button(window , text = "/" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_div.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_div.place(relx = 0.3 , rely = 0.8 , anchor = "center")

btn_equ = tk.Button(window , text = "=" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 9)
btn_equ.pack(side = "top")                 
btn_equ.place(relx = 0.24 , rely = 0.8 , anchor = "center")

btn_clear = tk.Button(window , text = "C" , fg = "#000000" , bg = "#ffffff" , height = 2 , width = 3)
btn_clear.pack(side = "top")
btn_clear.place(relx = 0.24 , rely = 0.5 , anchor = "center")
                     
window.mainloop()

num1 = float(input("Please enter your first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Please enter your second number: "))
operator = input("Please enter operator: ")

if operator == "4":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif operator == "1":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "2":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "3":
    print(num1 * num2)
else:
    print("ERROR >>>> please enter between 1 - 4 ")

num3 = num1 / num2
num3 = num1 - num2
num3 = num1 + num2
num3 = num1 * num2


continue1 =  input ("store result in the memory m [yes/no]: ")

if continue1 == "yes":
    operator1 = num4 = float(input("Please enter second number: "))
else:
    print("program terminated")

input("please enter operator: ")

if operator == "4":
    print(num3 / num4)
elif operator == "1":
    print(num3 + num4)
elif operator == "2":
    print(num3 - num4)
elif operator == "3":
    print(num3 * num4)
else:
    print("Please press enter to close: ")

input("Press Enter to Exit: ")
```

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try make a label & put your buttons in that, not in the main window so when you minimize window your buttons stay same in the label. but anyway it's better if you don't let users to minimize window by adding `window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)` to your code.

Comment: It's better just to use `grid()` and `pack()`, which automatically resize and reposition the widgets according to window size, instead of `place()`. Users should be able to resize the window, and this is not a good reason for making them unable to do so. Also, it's better to put buttons in a `Frame`, which is specifically designed for holding widgets, whereas a `Label` is not. But in this case, putting them directly in the window is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Can you explain the different attributes and functions of grid() function and how to create a frame. thank you for your help